# Mail getting stuck in queueu with Postfix/Spamassassin

Tags: linux, email, smtp, postfix, spamassassin

Happy Star Wars day everyone.

I'm having trouble with a fresh postfix + spamassassin + dovecot +amavis install on Debian Stretch.

Incoming mail is hung up in the queue with a "mail transport unavailable" error, until I manually run "postsuper -r ALL && postfix flush".

The only clue that anything is wrong is this error in mail.warn:

`mail postfix/qmgr[16088]: warning: connect to transport private/spamassassin: No such file or directory`

So I'm sure this is the culprit. I just have no idea what file/directory it's complaining about not being able to access. When I do flush the queue, spamassassin does it's job, and things are being properly filtered.

Here is my master.cf: https://pastebin.com/H7D50YpL

Output of "ps aux | grep spam":

`root     16928  0.2  4.4 172448 90464 ?        Ss   22:31   0:01 /usr/bin/perl -T -w /usr/sbin/spamd -d --pidfile=/var/run/spamd.pid --create-prefs --max-children 5 --helper-home-dir
root     16929  0.0  4.7 179560 97432 ?        S    22:31   0:00 spamd child
root     16930  0.0  4.7 179748 95952 ?        S    22:31   0:00 spamd child
postfix  17079  0.1  0.4 106972 10068 ?        S    22:43   0:00 smtpd -n smtp -t inet -u -c -o stress= -v -o content_filter=spamassassin
postfix  17082  0.1  0.4 106832 10036 ?        S    22:44   0:00 smtpd -n smtp -t inet -u -c -o stress= -v -o content_filter=spamassassin`

According to this article https://www.binarytides.com/install-spamassassin-with-postfix-dovecot/, when I run "netstat -nlp4 | grep spam" I should see spamc listening at 127.0.0.1:738, but I don't get anything listening on that port at all.

Although a "sudo netstat -l4 | grep spam" does return this:

`tcp        0      0 localhost:spamd         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Again, I'm sure spamassassin is holding up the show here.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that I needed to create a spamassassin directory under /var/spool/postfix/private. Things are running smoothly now.